# Ionic/Angular retrieve selected radio in a list

Tags: html, angularjs, list, radio-button, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic and I'm having a hard time retrieving selected radio buttons.

The following is my HTML

```
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="answer">
      <div class="item-content">
        Canada
      </div>
    <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="answer">
      <div class="item-content">
        Africa
      </div>
    <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="answer">
      <div class="item-content">
        North America
      </div>
    <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
  </label>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to approach that issue? Is there a way to access the model object from $scope after having selected the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any value attribute for your radio buttons. Set a value for your radio button and you can access the value using `$scope.answer`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding">
      Selected Answer {{answer}}
        <div class="list">
  <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="answer" value="Canada">
      <div class="item-content">
        Canada
      </div>
    <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="answer" value="Africa">
      <div class="item-content">
        Africa
      </div>
    <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="answer"  value="North America">
      <div class="item-content">
        North America
      </div>
    <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
  </label>
</div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My bad, I totally forgot about the value! Thank you very much! :-)